# Excluding Programs from the Program Compatibility Assistant

Tags: windows, registry

What are my options on excluding my program from the PCA in windows 8 and 10?

Should I just use the `VersionHelpers.h` and add a registry value like stated here:

> Another option to exclude applications from PCA is to add the list of
>   executable files with full path under the following registry key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Compatibility Assistant. The value name is
>   ExecutablesToExclude, which is type REG_MULTI_SZ.

But that note is taken from a [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545347), which is for windows 7.

My questions are:
1. Does this same approach still work for Windows 8 and 10?
2. Is there another alternative to this?
3. What do they mean by:

> PCA automatically excludes programs running from network locations and
>   programs containing fixes applied to them in the application
>   compatibility databases.

How do I do this `fixes applied to them in the application compatibility database`?

My program works fine on windows 8 and 10, if it doesn't add the registry values for my program on PCA. But if it does, my program just crashes. So I wish to exempt it.

Comment: Let me check if adding a manifest with compatibility to win8 and 10, could exclude it from the PCA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this also applies to Windows 8/10.

You can have a look at this page explaining about the [Compatibility Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749034(v=ws.10).aspx). Specifically, you need to either use it to manually apply a fix for your application, or use the [`sdbinst.exe` command line tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749169(v=ws.10).aspx).